# Deserialise Xml to List using Jackson failed

Tags: java, xml, list, class, jackson

Im trying to deserialise my Xml file and map it to my Class, it is working fine if I did not attach List to my class.

Ive already added static class,jsonIgnoreProperties, using XMLElementWrapper, but its still not working!

This is the method im calling.

```
File file = new File(test.xml);
XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
String xml = inputStreamToString(new FileInputStream(file));

Test test = xmlMapper.readValue(xml, Test.class);
```

Here is my class.

```
import java.util.List;
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.xml.annotate.JacksonXmlElementWrapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.xml.annotate.JacksonXmlRootElement;

@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "web-request-form")
public class Test {

@JsonProperty("attachments")
public Attachments attachments;

public Test(Attachments attachments) {
    super();
    this.attachments = attachments;
}

public Test() {
    super();
}

public Attachments getAttachments() {
    return attachments;
}

public void setAttachments(Attachments attachments) {
    this.attachments = attachments;
}

public static class Attachments {


    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName = "attachment")
    public List<Attachment> attachment;

    public Attachments() {
        super();
    }

    public Attachments(List<Attachment> attachment) {
        super();
        this.attachment = attachment;
    }

    public List<Attachment> getAttachment() {
        return attachment;
    }

    public void setAttachment(List<Attachment> attachment) {
        this.attachment = attachment;
    }
}

public static class Attachment {

    @JsonProperty("filename")
    public String fileName;

    @JsonProperty("desc")
    public String desc;

    @JsonProperty("size")
    public String size;

    public Attachment() {
        super();
    }

    public Attachment(String fileName, String desc, String size) {
        super();
        this.fileName = fileName;
        this.desc = desc;
        this.size = size;
    }

    public String getFileName() {
        return fileName;
    }

    public void setFileName(String fileName) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
    }

    public String getDesc() {
        return desc;
    }

    public void setDesc(String desc) {
        this.desc = desc;
    }

    public String getSize() {
        return size;
    }

    public void setSize(String size) {
        this.size = size;
    }
}
```

}

Here is my xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!--This file was generated from an ASPX file-->
<web-request-form xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="WebRequestForm.elms.xmlbeans.novacitynets.com">
 <attachments>
  <attachment>
    <filename>test</filename>
    <desc />
    <size>2089.801</size>
  </attachment>
 </attachments>
</web-request-form>
```

This is the error im getting.

```
Can not instantiate value of type [simple type, class 
package.Test$Attachment] from JSON String; no single-String 
constructor/factory method (through reference chain: 
package.Test["attachments"]->package.Attachments["attachment"])
```

Comment: What happens if you remove the multi-argument constructor from `Attachment`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure of your Jackson library version, but if you are using version 2.1 or later, Can you try this code below?
Also, it seems not good to mix `codehaus` and `fasterxml`.

try the following:

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlRootElement;

import java.util.List;

@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "web-request-form")
public class Test {
    @JsonProperty("attachments")
    public Attachments attachments;

    public static class Attachments {
        // @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName = "attachment")
        @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false, localName = "attachment")
        public List<Attachment> attachment;

        // ...
    }

    public static class Attachment {
        @JsonProperty("filename")
        public String fileName;

        @JsonProperty("desc")
        public String desc;

        @JsonProperty("size")
        public String size;

        // ...
    }
}
```

If you have applied the `useWrapping` option to the `JacksonXmlElementWrapper`annotation, nothing will change. Call the method as follows:

```java
File file = new File("test.xml");

// If you use the useWrapping option globally
// JacksonXmlModule module = new JacksonXmlModule();
// module.setDefaultUseWrapper(false);

XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper(module);
String xml = inputStreamToString(new FileInputStream(file));
Test test = xmlMapper.readValue(xml, Test.class);
```

Comment: Thanks!! You were right about not mixing codehaus and fasterxml. Used another Jackson library and made changes above and it worked perfectly..

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to parse it by

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
  <version>2.9.8</version>
</dependency>
```

Entity:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlElementWrapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlRootElement;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "web-request-form")
public class WebRequestForm {

    public Attachments attachments;

    public static class Attachments {

        @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
        public List<Attachment> attachment = new ArrayList<>();

    }

    public static class Attachment {

        @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "filename")
        public String fileName;

        public String desc;

        public String size;

    }
}
```

Parser:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper;
import java.io.IOException;

    public class WebRequestFormParser {

        public WebRequestForm parse(String sampleXMLContent) throws IOException {
            XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
            WebRequestForm result = xmlMapper.readValue(sampleXMLContent, WebRequestForm.class);
            return result;
        }
    }
```

Please see project https://github.com/sbzDev/stackoverflow/tree/master/question56087719
with unit test